# Add column to several files, combine in one file and sort it

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am new to the Python world, and I am fighting with basic operations.
I have a huge amount of files named `inlet_10_00_00.csv`, `inlet_10_00_01.csv`, `inlet_10_00_02.csv`, etc. corresponding to different time inlet_Hour_minute_sec.
The content looks like:

```
x, y, z, temperature, pressure, u, v, w, k , omega

0, 0, 0, 295, 100001, ...

0, 1, 1, 296, 100002, ...

...
```

I would like to do the next 2 operations:

1/ Add a `t` column to each file with value `0` for `inlet_10_00_00`, value `1` for `inlet_10_00_01`, etc. Adding a column `t` for a single file was quite easy with `cols` tools. But how can I add it to all files?

```
data=pd.read_csv('C:/myPath/inlet_10_00_00.csv',sep=',',skiprows=7)
data["t (s)"]="0"
cols=list(data.columns.values)
cols=  cols[0:3]+ cols[-1:] + cols[3:10]
cols
newdata=data[cols]
newdata.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

2/ I want to combine all these files in one file and sort it by the `t` variable. I should end up with such format:
    x, y, z, t, temperature,pressure, u, v, w, k , omega

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 295,100001, ....   this part comes from inlet_10_00_00.csv

0, 1, 1, 0, 296,100002, ...

0, 0, 0, 1, 292,100008, ...    this part comes from inlet_10_00_01.csv

0, 1, 1, 1, 294,100012, ...
```

Any ideas, how to proceed?

Comment: "value 0 for `inlet_10_00_00`, value 1 for `inlet_10_00_01`" -- but what value for `inlet_11_11_11`?

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should help you achieve the expected result.

**Explanation:**

1.*Step 1:* Here we'll list the file names in the current directory. Then, we'll sort the file names to ensure files are looped in desired sequence.

2.*Step 2:* Here we'll iterate through the list we created in step 1, read a file, add a column and save the data frame with the same name.

3.*Step 3:* Finally, using `pd.concat` we join all the files in a data frame and sort the data frame by `t`.

```
# Step 1
path = 'C:/myPath/'
files = sorted(os.listdir(path)) # sorting will ensure _001, 002, 003 will bein sequence


## Step 2 
for ix, file in enumerate(files,1):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=7) ## assuming you want to skip first 7 rows in every file
    df['t'] = ix
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(path, file), index=False)

## Step 3
master_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])
master_df = master_df.sort_values('t').reset_index()
```

Comment: `os.path.join(path, 'file')` this overwrites the same file each time... Did you mean `os.path.join(path, file)`?

Comment: Glad to know. If it helps, don't forget to accept the answer.